# Split file into separate cells of excel based on pattern

Tags: linux, shell

I have a large file that's a couple hundred lines long. This file is partitioned into many parts by a specific separator,'###'. This line '###' appears after a couple of lines which may vary each time.So I need the content before '###' to be in one cell of a single excel file and contents after '###' to be in separate cell of same excel file.[image] I'm familiar with split and awk but can't seem to create a command line that will do what I've described, any ideas?

Comment: How do you make this Excel file, and how do you then read it?

Comment: @MichaelHomer - I redirect the output of text file to a .xls file . There is where I need this formatting to be done.

Comment: That is not how xls files work, nor xlsx files. Are you saying you've made a text file and called it `something.xls`?

Comment: @MichaelHomer  yes exactly

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/117549)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an executable script, test.awk, with following contents:

```
awk '
  # { system( "echo \"" $0 "\" >&2") }
  BEGIN { R = "\"" }
  /^###/ {
    sub(/\n$/,"",R)
    print R "\""
    R = "\""
    next
  }
  {
    sub(/\n$/,"")
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"")
    R = R $0 "\n"
  }
' $@
```

then run

```
test.awk  longfile.txt  > longfile.csv
```

Open longfile.csv with libreoffice Calc.

longfile.txt:

```
dkdkdkdk
qsdfqlsdf
qsdfjqlsdf
######
qdfqj
qsdfmlkjqsd
qsiapriopazeiru
wqsdfqesr
######
rurururururururuur
rururururururururu
ururururururururur
######
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
######
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
######
```

longfile.csv:

```
"dkdkdkdk
qsdfqlsdf
qsdfjqlsdf"
"qdfqj
qsdfmlkjqsd
qsiapriopazeiru
wqsdfqesr"
"rurururururururuur
rururururururururu
ururururururururur"
"iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii
iiiiiiiiiiii"
"uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuuuu"
```